# Checkboxes, Boolean Values, and Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, spree

I've created a form which asks for a user's information, and displays what is in their cart along with its price and a subtotal. Once they submit this form, they go to a show page with the information on it, and at the bottom is a "Create Quote" button, that generates a PDF quote for their hypothetical purchase .

Here's my problem: I would like to have a checkbox on the form for users who represent nonprofits, so that a discount can be applied. I would like this discount to appear on the "show" page after the information has been submitted (and later on the pdf generated, but one problem at a time). I've created a column in the quotes database for a boolean value of "nonprofit" to that end. I'm pretty green to programming in general, so I've been reading everything I can find on rails and checkboxes but the information's been either non-applicable, dated, or too hard to follow.

For the record, I'm aware that the code as it stands has serious security issues (anyone can look up any quote right now), which I intend to tackle later on. I've also tried to shorten my code here, since a lot of files are used.

Controller:

```
module Spree
class QuotesController < Spree::BaseController
before_action :set_quote, only: [:edit, :destroy, :show]

# GET /quotes
# GET /quotes.json
helper Spree::StoreHelper
helper Spree::BaseHelper
include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Order

def current_currency
  (defines currency)
end

# GET /quotes/1
# GET /quotes/1.json
def show
end

# GET /quotes/new
def new
  @quote = Quote.new
  if current_order
    @quote.set_order(current_order)
  else
    redirect_to :back, notice: Spree.t(:your_order_is_empty_add_product)
  end
end

# GET /quotes/1/edit
def edit

end

# POST /quotes
# POST /quotes.json
def create
  @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)
  @quote.set_order(current_order)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @quote.save
      format.html { redirect_to @quote, notice: 'Quote was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @quote }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @quote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /quotes/1
# PATCH/PUT /quotes/1.json
def update
  set_quote
  (updates quote)
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /quotes/1
# DELETE /quotes/1.json
def destroy
  (destroys quote)
  end
end

def pdf
  set_quote
  template = params[:template] || "quote"
  render :layout => false, :template => "spree/quotes/#{template}.pdf.prawn"
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_quote
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def quote_params
    params.require(:quote).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :company, :address1, :address2, :city, :country, :state, :zipcode, :phone, :email, :other)
  end
  end
  end
```

Model:

```
module Spree
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :first_name, :last_name, :address1, :city, :country, presence: true
    has_many :quote_line_items


    def set_order(order)
  total = 0
        order.line_items.each do |item|
            l = QuoteLineItem.new
            l.sku = item.variant.product.sku 
            l.description = item.variant.product.name + " " + item.variant.options_text
            l.quantity = item.quantity
            l.price = item.variant.product.price
    l.peritemsubtotal = item.variant.product.price * item.quantity
    total = total + l.peritemsubtotal
            l.quote = self
            #l.save!
            quote_line_items << l
        end

        self.subtotal = total

    end 
(this is just one of several attempts I've made).
    def adjustments
        if self.nonprofit == true
                total = total * 0.85
            end
        self.total = total
    end
    end
    end
```

New.html.erb just says "render _form", so here's _form

```
<%= form_for(@quote) do |f| %>
<% if @quote.errors.any? %>
(throws error message)
<% end %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :first_name %><br>
<%= f.text_field :first_name, :class => 'required' %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :last_name %><br>
<%= f.text_field :last_name, :class => 'required' %>

(etc. for other pertinent fields)

<%=Spree.t(:which_product)%>
<%= render :partial => '/spree/shared/product_quote' %>
<%= render :partial => '/spree/shared/adjustments'%>

<%= button_tag("Create Quote") %>
<% end %>
```

_adjustments:

```
<%=Spree.t(:special_circumstances)%>
<br>
<%= check_box_tag(:nonprofit)%>
<%= label_tag(:nonprofit, "This product is for a nonprofit")%>
<br>
```

...and the show page:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
<strong>First name:</strong>
<%= @quote.first_name %>
</p>

<p>
<strong>Last name:</strong>
<%= @quote.last_name %>
</p>

(etc. for other fields)

<!--There needs to be some code in here to display what adjustments were selected-->

<p>Final Total: <%= @quote.total %> </p>

<%= button_to "Print Quote", "/quotes/#{@quote.id}/pdf", :method => "get" %>
<br>
<p> <%= Spree.t(:is_correct) %> 
<%= link_to 'Edit Information.', edit_quote_path(@quote) %> </p>
<br>
<%= link_to 'Back', quotes_path %>
```

I think I'm just fundamentally misunderstanding how checkboxes work, but as I've been unsuccessful in finding something to help, I'm asking you all.

EDIT: Whether or not someone chooses to be a nonprofit also needs to be registered in our database, not just in the display of the show page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form just add

```
   <%= f.check_box :nonprofit %>
```

And then an if statement in the show page